# Can a designer get hold of the PCI Express specification without being a member of the PCI SIG group?

Tags: pcie

I want to get hold of the PCI Express specification which is available [here](http://www.pcisig.com/specifications/pciexpress/base3/)
. But when I try to download it, it asks me to login as a member - which requires membership at $3000 per year.

Is it possible to get hold of the specification without being a member, or having to pay this very high fee?

Comment: Yes. A good search engine is your friend for this. Lots and lots of people publish things they shouldn't either intentionally or more often accidentally. Practice you google-fu. Start with "PCI Express specification filetype:pdf" and tune from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, no.  Of course people will pirate lots of things they shouldn't.

You get more than just access to the spec for that $3K.  You get a PCIe Vendor ID number, which is required if you want to make a product that uses PCIe.

But...  Do you really need the official spec?  Probably 90% of the spec is only useful for people who are designing chips (not even FPGA's).  Do you really care about the low-level signal encoding, or the more esoteric state machines?  If not then there are books on PCIe that will likely be more useful to you than the spec will be.  [PCI Express System Architecture](http://amzn.com/0321156307) is one such book that can almost replace the spec, but there are many others.

Comment: What is funny however is that things like the PCI firmware specification still cost $1000.